# Is it possible to use a different modules in AngularJS based on a config change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I kind of understand how DI works with modules in AngularJS and I was hoping to take advantage of that to be able to use a different module depending on the environment of the application.

For example, I want to make something that can run on both a mobile device (using Phonegap) as well as in a regular desktop browser.

There is  service function that I want to use for data access.  On the device, I just want it to query the local database on the device.  For the desktop browser version, I want it to query a web service.

So for example, I want 2 services that can be interchanged:

```
angular.module('myDataServiceLocalStorage', [])
  .factory('dataSrv', [function () {
      return {
          getOrders: function () {
             //get from database
          }
      };
  } ])
;

angular.module('myDataServiceWebService', [])
  .factory('dataSrv', [function () {
      return {
          getOrders: function () {
             //get from web service
          }
      };
  } ])
;
```

In my angular controllers, I could inject either myDataServiceLocalStorage or myDataServiceWebService to get access to the `getOrders` function, but how can I configure this better to use one or the other among all of my controllers?

I don't necessarily need it to detect the environment automatically, but is there a way I can do this so that I don't have to globally search and replace each module reference everytime I prepare to deploy the project?

I was thinking about doing something with providers, but I am confused and I don't think that is their main purpose (looks like Angular providers just modify a single existing service before it is instantiated)

Is something like this even possible?

Comment: You shouldn't need to handle/change the injection. Create one factory that is always injected wherever needed. Inside the factory, you can either have the individual methods (like `getOrders`) or the entire object `return`ed, use logic to use the correct methods (local storage vs. web service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have had a similar requirement and what i did was created separate factories for each device per say.

```
app.factory("deviceOneFactory", function(){
   var renderOne = function(params) {
     // logic for rendering typeOneChart
   };

   return {
      render : renderOne
   }
})

app.factory("deviceTwoFactory", function(){
   var renderTwo = function(params) {
     // logic for rendering typeTwoChart
   };

   return {
      render : renderTwo
   }
})
```

so you have above to factories, returning same set of function names , so its kind of implementing an interface.

and then there is a parent factory which keep other part of application agnostic of this section

```
app.factory("deviceFactory", function(){

   var localFactory ;

   var deviceFactory = function(){
     switch(devicetype) {
        case 'one':
           localFactory = typeOneDevice;
           break;
        case 'two':
           localFactory = typeTwoDetive;
           break;
        default:
           throw exception("invalid device type : " + deviceType);
     }
   }

   var render = function(params) {
     localFactory.render();
   };

   return {
      render : render
   }
})
```

Note: above code is not exact, it just to give you an idea.

Comment: Yes, I think this is what I need for mine as well, thank you.  Have you any idea of how to enforce each sub-factory to have the same set of functions? I was thinking of just adding test cases to check for function existance, but not sure if there is a better way.